# Stop a System.Timers.Timer which re-enables itself inside its elapsed event handler

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer

I have a **Timer** that polls an external service. The poll can take a while, so I use a one-shot Timer(`System.Timers.Timer`) and re-enable it when the operation completes, so I have only one running poll at a time. Now I need to stop this timer externally using the reference and prevent the event from restarting it in a separate thread.

```
System.Timers.Timer pollTimer = new System.Timers.Timer {
    Enabled = true,
    AutoReset = false,
    Interval = 4 * 1000,
};

pollTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(
    (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {

        if (!PollSuccess()) 
        {
            ((System.Timers.Timer) sender).Start();
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Work
        }

    });

// I want the timer to stop permanently here, ie prevent the elapsed 
//event handler from restarting it.

pollTimer.Stop();
```

Comment: `Dispose()` it ?

Comment: Oy yeah. Thanks. That will do. But what if I dispose it in one thread, but the elapsed event handler references it some time later, wouldn't it cause an exception?

Comment: I suggest Dispose because you said permanently. Yes it will throw exception.

Comment: Why not just set a flag and then if the flag is set when the handler goes to re-enable the timer (i.e. after the poll fails), _don't re-enable the timer_?

Comment: @PeterDuniho My example above is a bit oversimplified, I was looking for a cleaner solution than passing around flags, but I ended up doing what you said and it works :)